# Pixastic javascript library is returning false in image tag when i am trying to use it in Windows 8 Metro Style app in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am trying to use Pixastic JavaScript library for image manipulation in Windows 8 Metry Style app using JavaScript as language. I am passing canvas as input parameter and trying to get image and binging again to canvas but the image value that i am getting all the time is FALSE. 
CODE:

```
 // First, draw it into the backing canvas
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

    // change brightness and contrast
    Pixastic.Client.isIE = false;
    Pixastic.process(canvas, 'brightness',
        {
            'brightness': 2,
            'contrast': 0.0,
            'leaveDOM': true
        },
        function (img) {

            if (img) {
                context.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    );
```

I tried to find the reason and its said that this class returns false only if there is an internal error or some other problem occurs. when i debugged the code its runs fine no issue with my written code. But when i check inside Pixastic library i found that on one condition check its returning false

```
if(imageIsCanvas&&Pixastic.Client.isIE()){if(Pixastic.debug)writeDebug("Tried to process a canvas element but browser is IE.");return false;
```

I don't know how can i use Pixastic in my Windows 8 app. Can anyone suggest a way to use pixastic library in Windows 8 app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Pixastic doesn't support IE. From their [website:](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/)

> The methods are currently only fully supported by Firefox, Opera and
>   Safari with a recent WebKit nightly build.

You could change your isIE workaround to either be a function (as below) or change the implementation in the library.

```
Pixastic.Client.isIE  = function(){ return false; };
```

Though no doubt other things could be broken.