# Need third party JavaScript for image manipulation using Canvas HTML5 in Windows 8 Metro Style app?

Tags: html, canvas, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am working on an app in Windows 8 Metro Style app. I need a third party javascript which can provide multiple image manipulation effects. Which i can use in my application. So is there any third party javascript which can help me in that.

NOTE:- I need for Windows 8 HTML5 canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this library: [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/)

Comment: yes but i am getting some error in that for which i have already posted a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857937/pixastic-javascript-library-is-returning-false-in-image-tag-when-i-am-trying-to